# Erro ao inserir dados PHP MySql usando a lib volley do Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, volley

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que terá que enviar dados para um servidor.

Meu código fonte do php é este:

**connection.php**

```
<?php
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysql_user = "root";
    $mysql_password = "";
    $mysql_database = "app";

    $db = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
    mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $db) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

?>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
        error_reporting(0);
        include("connection.php");

       // vetor response
       $response = array();

       if( !(empty($_POST['matricula']))){
           //variaveis recebendo os valores pelo método POST
           $matricula=$_POST['matricula'];
           $cpf=$_POST['cpf'];
           $placa=$_POST['placa'];

           $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO myorder(idUser,matricula,cpf,placa) VALUES('','$matricula','$cpf','$placa')");   
           if($result>0){
              $response["success"] = 1;
           }   
           else{
              $response["success"] = 0;
           }

        echo json_encode($response);
      }

?>
```

Do **xml**:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/et_cad_matr_car"
    android:hint="@string/text_view_matricula_cad"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_cad_main2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/et_cad_cpf"
    android:hint="@string/texte_view_cpf"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_cad_matr_car"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/et_placa_car"
    android:hint="@string/et_placa_car"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_cad_cpf"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_cad_ok"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_placa_car"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="insert"/>
```

Então criei uma classe chamada **ConMain2.java** para colocar vários métodos da lib volley.

Os métodos `getInstance()`, `getReqQueue()`, `addToReqQueue()`.

```
package br.fepi.caronasfepi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
public class ConMain2 extends AppCompatActivity {

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private static ConMain2 mInstance;

public static synchronized ConMain2 getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getReqQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToReqQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {

    getReqQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToReqQueue(Request<T> req) {

    getReqQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingReq(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
 }
```

}

E por fim minha activity **Main2.java**

```
package br.fepi.caronasfepi;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Main2 extends AppCompatActivity {


   EditText matricula;
   EditText cpf;
   EditText placa;
   String item_matricula;
   String item_cpf;
   String item_placa;
   RequestQueue requestQ;
   ProgressDialog PD;
   String url = "000.000.000.000/insert.php";

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);//chamando o arquivo xml para a classe


    PD = new ProgressDialog(this);
    PD.setMessage("Carregando.....");
    PD.setCancelable(false);

    matricula = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_cad_matr_car);
    cpf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_cad_cpf);
    placa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_placa_car);
}
    public void insert(View v){

        PD.show();
        item_matricula = matricula.getText().toString();
        item_cpf = cpf.getText().toString();
        item_placa = placa.getText().toString();
            StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    PD.dismiss();
                    matricula.setText("");
                    cpf.setText("");
                    placa.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Data Inserted Successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    PD.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("matricula", item_matricula);
                    params.put("cpf", item_cpf);
                    params.put("placa", item_placa);
                    return params;
                }
            };
        ConMain2.getInstance().addToReqQueue(postRequest);
        }




public void back_tb(View View) {
    finish();
}
}
```

Estou testando a url pelo IP do meu servidor.

O erro é que quando clico no botão de inserir dados aparece a seguinte mensagem

> "Unfortunately app has stopped"

E não insere nada no banco.

Eu estou seguindo este [tutorial](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/12/android-php-insert-mysql-db-volley.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analisando o código postado e tendo por base o tutorial citado, julgo que o erro se dá na linha `ConMain2.getInstance().addToReqQueue(postRequest);`

A razão primeira é que a classe *ConMain2* não inicializa a variável `mInstance` que é retornada pelo método `ConMain2.getInstance()`.

Se verificar o código que implementou verá que ele não está de acordo com o tutorial, nos seguintes aspectos:

- A classe *ConMain2* deverá herdar de *Application* e não de *AppCompatActivity*
- Deve ser implementado o método `onCreate()`, onde é inicializada a variável `mInstance`.

Faça a seguintes alterações:

Altere

```
public class ConMain2 extends AppCompatActivity
```

para

```
public class ConMain2 extends Application
```

Implemente o método `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}
```

O tutorial não faz referência mas é necessário, para que a classe *ConMain2* seja criada, incluir no *AndroidManifest.xml* dentro da *tag* `<application>`o seguinte atributo:

```
android:name=".ConMain2"
```

Permita-me uma pequena nota:
O uso de tutoriais é muito útil. Tudo o que aprendi relacionado com *Android* foi recorrendo a eles.
Mas, há sempre um mas, isso só foi conseguido porque sempre me esforcei por entender como o código funciona antes de o utilizar.
Só se aprende compreendendo.

Comment: Muito obrigada, solucionou meu problema este meu problema! Mais ainda não insere dados no banco de dados.

Comment: O código PHP está correcto? Não esqueça de colocar um **ip** válido em `String url = "000.000.000.000/insert.php";`

Comment: Reformulei a pergunta, com os erros que aparece no logcat

Comment: O problema ("Unfortunately app has stopped") colocado nesta pergunta esta resolvido. Você deve criar outra pergunta e expor o novo problema.

Comment: Ok, fiz uma outra pergunta que se encontra neste link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99499/dados-n%C3%A3o-s%C3%A3o-inseridos-do-android-para-o-mysql-usando-volley